# Pokken Tournament DX Skill Points?

Tags: pokken-tournament-dx

The skill points I assign to my various pokemons like attack/defense/synergy, do these actually affect online game play or are they just for single player only? It doesn't really make sense for this to affect online gameplay in a fighting game....

I looked online for answers but they only related to the original Pokken game, not the Switch version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The Prima Games guide](https://www.primagames.com/games/pokken-tournament/feature/pokken-tournament-dx-new-characters-and-differences) discussing the version differences seems to indicate that there are no core gameplay differences between the Wii U and Nintendo Switch version of this game. The main differences are the playable characters, improved frame rate/graphics, and new game modes.

> **The main difference between the two versions is the capabilities of the Switch. This means higher quality of graphics, frame rate and of course the ability to play this game anywhere.** [...] Pokken Tournament DX has the more playable characters than the Wii U and arcade versions. [...] There are also new ways to play in DX, like 3v3 matches and online groups with your friends to see who is really the very best like no one ever was. There’s also a replay mode that lets you watch previous matches, which also shows your button inputs to help you learn more about the game and analyze your matches better. Finally, there are daily challenges that you can do to unlock some nice rewards for your Pokemon.
>
> All in all the differences between DX and the other versions of Pokken Tournament are not hugely substantial. **There’s nothing new that completely changes the core of the game, which is a good thing. It’s very similar to Mario Kart 8 Deluxe in that it is just the best version of the game out there right now.**

As observed in [this PSA for the Wii U edition](https://www.reddit.com/r/PokkenGame/comments/4b8tbi/skill_points_do_affect_online/), skill points definitely affected online matches. Since the Switch version kept the core gameplay the same, it seems highly unlikely that this has changed.